# How to insert 'tabindex=-1 attribute' to jQuery Nice Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I changed some codes of jQuery [Nice Select - v1.1.0](https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select) and applied to website. Modified codes are below, and it creates div which has class value of 'scroll-pane' and overflow value of 'hidden'.

The problem is that the div has `tabindex='0'` by default, so whenever I'm tabbing I'm supposed to pass through the hidden div. I tried to change default value of `tabindex='0'` to `tabindex='-1'` but couldn't find a way. It seems that `getElementsByClass` and `.setAttribute()` are don't apply like to this situation.

```
if ($dropdown.find('ul').height() > 241 || $dropdown.find('ul').height() == 0) {
    var pane = $dropdown.find('ul').wrap('<div class="scroll-pane"></div>').parent();
    var listWidth = $dropdown.find('.list_wrap').css("width");
    console.log(listWidth);
    pane.css({
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'height': '241px',
    });
    pane.bind('jsp-initialised', function (e, _isScroll) {
        isScroll = _isScroll;
        if (isScroll) {
            //non .jspPane scroll padding
            var jspPane = pane.find('.jspPane');
            jspPane.css('width', otWidth);
        }
    });
    pane.jScrollPane({});
}
```

Comment: `.attr("tabindex","1")` to set attribute

Comment: Possibly relevant ... from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex), "If we set the tabindex attribute on a <div>, then its child content cannot be scrolled using arrow keys unless we set tabindex on the content too".

Comment: @guradio Where should I put .attr("tabindex","1")? I'm sorry I'm not really familiar with javascript syntax